# Puppet Learning VM with Jenkins CI installation

Tags: centos, continuous-integration, puppet

I am trying to set up Jenkins CI in Puppet Learning VM ( CentOS 6.5 x86 ), but I cannot make yum to see openjdk 1.7.0 packages, therefore jenkins puppet fails.

I have tried adding epel repo - still yum says no package available. I have changed pluginconf to disable yum protection and still no go. What else can I do ...?

See second comment for screenshot.

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: Sorry, could not copy from VBoxed screen, so took screenshot: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-oZOupS2ytFY/VWSBkVkIvjI/AAAAAAAAF-E/1zznEa8mdsc/w720-h400-no/learn_puppet_centos-6.5.png

Comment: what happens if you try `yum search openjdk` manually

Comment: I tried. Yum finds only 1.6.0 package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That VM might have intentionally disabled repos. Check files in 
`ls -la /etc/yum.repos.d/`

java-1.7.0-openjdk should be available in base repo so check the contents of file `CentOS-Base.repo`, look for `enabled=0` and change to `enabled=1`

After that, try `yum search openjdk`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the CentOS-Base.repo was fully disabled. Much appreciated!